# Set permissions to a group

Tags: permissions

It is possible to set permissions to an group? For example, I want that the group "sales" has the permission 644. So, after I add an user to this group, automatically the user will get those permissions. Afterwards, I want to change the permissions to the group "sales", so all users associated with this group have new permissions.

Does this make sense in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it a little bit wrong there. Basic version (it is a little more intricate):

You can set a file or directory for 3 identities: owner, group, and other. Owner is a user, group is a collection of users, other is everyone else. A file or directory has 3 permissions: read, write, and execute for each of the 3 identities.

If you want a group to be able to execute a file that file needs to be at least `---rwx---`. The 1st 3 and last 3: owner (if not in group), other are not allowed to do anything. Middle 3: users belonging to group can read, write, and execute.

So ...

> It is possible to set permissions to an group?

No, owner, group, and permissions are set for "files" and "directories".

> For example, I want that the group "sales" has the permission 644

That would not be 644, it would be `rwx` for read, write, execute so that is one digit in total for groups not 3 (1=r, 2=w, 4=x where 6 is wx and 4 is x)

> after I add an user to this group, automatically the user will get those permissions.

No, you add a user to a group and when a user does something with a file or directory that has this group set the permissions are checked on both "user" and "group" (so if user owns the file those permissions are checked too; if user can execute and group can not the file IS executed).

There is no method to transfer group permissions to the user. That is done by adding or removing the user to a group. Unless you manually execute a command that does that.

> Afterwards, I want to change the permissions to the group "sales", so all users associated with this group have new permissions.

I understand and there sort of a way but you need to do it on each directory you want this and need to re-apply it every time. If you change to a directory this will set the sticky bit with:

```
chmod g+s {dir}
```

This will make it so that all new files and directories created inside {dir} are set to the group of {dir} itself. Next you can do this to set d(efaults) for g(group) as "rwx" (remove x if you don't want execute) for {dir}:

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx {dir}
```

(use capital letter (X for execute) if it only needs to be applied to directories) and this will show the defaults for that directory.

```
getfacl {dir}
```

After every change you need to apply the permissions you need to re-apply them:

```
setfacl -R -m g::rwx {dir}
```

recursively changes all. Only excutable would be:

```
setfacl -R -m o::x {dir}
```

- never ever do this on the `/` as it will totally wreck a system

You could create 2 scripts with these commands:

```
chmod g+s {dir}
setfacl -d -m g::rwx {dir}
setfacl -R -m g::rwx {dir}
```

and

```
chmod g+s {dir}
setfacl -d -m g::rw- {dir}
setfacl -R -m g::rw- {dir}
```

and toggle between them: 1 adds execute, the other removes it.
If you replace "g" by "u" or add a line for "u" you can also change "user"